# Unmanaged Exports, passing an array of strings from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, c#-4.0, interop

I'm using [Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) package to be able to call from C++ to C#. 
This has to use the C interface from within C++. I have managed to get most things working, by scouring the web and picking up bits here and there....

```
extern "C"
{
    //  Simple
    __declspec(dllimport) int IntTest(int input);
    __declspec(dllimport) double DoubleTest(double input);

    //  Array of simple types in
    __declspec(dllimport) int passArray(int t[], int i, int xx);

    //  String in and out
    __declspec(dllimport) int PassStringIn(wchar_t* str);
    __declspec(dllimport) int PassStringOut(wchar_t** str);
    __declspec(dllimport) wchar_t* PassStringInOut(wchar_t* str);

    //  Array of strings types in
    //__declspec(dllimport) int passArrayStrings(char** t, int i);
}
```

....

```
//  Int in and out
int aa = IntTest(4);

//  Double in and out
double bb = DoubleTest(4.3);

//  Pass array in
int arr[4] = { 1,2,3,4 };
int cc = passArray(arr, 4, 0);

//  String in
wchar_t* a_str = L"input string from C++";
int dd = PassStringIn(a_str);

//  String out
wchar_t* b_str = L"not used";
int ee = PassStringOut(&b_str);

//  String in & out
wchar_t* d_str = L"bob";
wchar_t* result = PassStringInOut(d_str);
```

corresponding C#

```
    [DllExport( CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static int IntTest(int input)
    {
        return input + 1;
    }

    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static double DoubleTest(double input)
    {
        return input + 1;
    }

    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int passArray([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]  int[] tab, int i, int x)
    {
        return tab[x];
    }

    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int PassStringIn( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string inputString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, the string passed in was :" + inputString);
        return 1;
    }

    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static int PassStringOut([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string outputString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, I will return the time from c#");
        outputString = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        return 0; // indicates success
    }

    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public static string PassStringInOut([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello from .NET assembly, {0}!", name);
    }
```

[Which was nice!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOhZgAPn_CU) Anyway would anybody be able to help with passing arrays of strings in and out. I am pretty sure the C# section should look like this:

```
    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int passArrayStrings( [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]  string[] tab, int i)
    {

        return 1;
    }
```

I need some help on the C++(C) side on how to structure the array of strings in, such that they can be marshaled correctly. The mixed mode assembly created has both C# and and a C interface. As it is C and not C++ the arguments types of the exposed functions are not visible.

[image: Dependency Walker]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use an IntPtr parameter.

You'll have to allocate unmanaged memory and copy the array into that blob anyway. Otherwise the GC will eat your array at some point.

[Unmanaged Exports with Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934016/unmanaged-exports-with-arrays/15025215#15025215)

Comment: I'd appreciate to learn what you think that I did wrong. Just down voting doesn't really help does it?

Comment: Hi Robert, I am the one who asked the question, but I did not down vote this answer, not sure who did? In fact I have only just logged in to stack overflow and seen your answer. Let me study your answer and get back to you. Thanks Sean

Comment: Hi Robert,  I got it going in the end. I used BSTR arrays:

Answer (score 3):

ok so after a lot of messing about I came to a solution:

```
//  Array of strings types in
__declspec(dllimport) int passArrayStrings(BSTR* bstrArray, int i);

BSTR bstrArray[10] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    bstrArray[i] = ::SysAllocString(L"My String.");
}
int ff = passArrayStrings(bstrArray, 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ::SysFreeString(bstrArray[i]);
}
```

and on the c# side:

```
    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int passArrayStrings([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.BStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]  string[] tab, int iSize)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```